# Phalcon Direct Flash message not loading properly in view

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm currently learning phalcon: still a crude beginner though. I want to create an registration section for my web app. Currently I have:

> a controller named AuthController
>       with actions: index[login logic], register[registration logic]
>   a login viewviews/auth/index.phtml.
>   a registration view as views/auth/register.phtml with form posting to auth/register

Also using Twitter Bootstrap for the frontend.

I'm currently trying to validate passwords. If its not equal, display a flash message.

Code for register action:

```
if($this -> request -> isPost())
        {
            $name = $this -> request -> getPost('fullname');
            $username = $this -> request -> getPost('email');
            $password = $this -> request -> getPost('password');
            $vpassword = $this -> request -> getPost('cpassword');

            if($password != $vpassword)
            {
                $this -> flash -> error("The passwords doesn't match!!!");
                //return $this -> view -> pick('register'); //Show page/ no error msg
                /*return $this->dispatcher->forward(        //show error/ no page / cyclic routing
                    [
                        'controller'    => 'auth',
                        'action'        => 'register'
                    ]
                );*/
                // Make a full HTTP redirection
                //return $this->response->redirect('auth/register');
            }
```

Currently, if I use:

```
return $this -> view -> pick('register');
```

I get the view back, but without the flash error message

And also, if I use;

```
return $this->dispatcher->forward(
                    [
                        'controller'    => 'auth',
                        'action'        => 'register'
                    ]
                );
```

I get the error message displayed multiple times, no view. I think cyclic routing is happening but shouldn't the isPost() check prevent that? And if it was POST'ed, the values in the password field would be the same.

```
Any ideas?
```

Comment: Have you built your app as `Micro` or `Full`? 
Also can you show example of your dispatcher where you assigning flash and template where you rendering it?

Answer (score 0):

Your got your session set before setting the flash in your injector?
Initializing the session and flash:

```
/**
* Start the session
*/

$di->set('session', function() {
    $session = new \Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Files();
    $session->start();
    return $session;
}, true);

/**
* Register the flash service with custom CSS classes
*/

$di->set('flash', function() {
    $flash = new \Phalcon\Flash\Session([
        'error' => 'alert alert-danger',
        'success' => 'alert alert-success',
        'notice' => 'alert alert-info',
    ]);

    return $flash;
});
```

Comment: I think I get it now. Use Phalcon\Flash\Direct to display a message without picking a view or doing a redirect. Otherwise, use Phalcon\Flash\Session.